# += with strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I was playing around with strings in C++ and I don't understand why the following causes an error when compiled:

```
string s = "hi";
s += " " + "there!";
```

Error message:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [2]’ and ‘const char [6]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

I also tried `s+= (" " + "there!");` and it doesn't work either.

Why can't I use the binary operator `+=` to concatenate the strings this way?

Comment: Tell us the error message, or it didn't happen.

Comment: It's kind of implicit with some of the existing answers, but worth mentioning that the C++ precedence rules mean that `" " + "there!"` is evaluated before the `s +=` operation, so the parentheses you also tried didn't make any difference.  Interestingly, `s += " " "there!"` would work - concatenation of adjacent string literals is done in an earlier phase of compilation, and `s = s + " " + "there!"` would also work as `s + " "` is evaluated first, then the `std::string` result thereof has "there!" added - when either argument to `+` is a `std::string` it works just fine....

Comment: +1 Thank you Tony for these details!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to "add" two literal strings.  Literal strings are not of the type std::string in C++, they are like immutable arrays of characters.  Adding two together does not make sense, as it would be like adding two pointers together.

You can, however, do this:

```
std::string("foo") + "bar"
```

This is because there are methods defined in C++ to concatenate C++ strings with C strings.

Comment: How does "s = s + " " + "there!";" work, then? Is "s+" "" being performed, resulting in a std::string, then the "+"there"" part done, again against a std::string?  What is the technical difference between a+=b and a=a+b ?

Comment: `s + "there"` works because there is an overloaded operator for `string + const char*`.  There's usually no difference between `a+=b` and `a=a+b` in C++, but a library implementer could make there be some difference if they were evil.

Answer (score 9):

Literal strings aren't string objects, they're just arrays of characters. When you try to add them like that, they decay into pointers to the arrays - and you can't add a pair of pointers. If you convert the first literal to a string object, it will work as you expect.

```
s += string(" ") + "there!";
```

You can also concatenate literals just by putting them next to each other without the `+`.

```
s += " "  "there!";
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try it I get:

```
632 $ g++ foo.C
foo.C: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.C:5:16: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [2]’ and ‘const char [7]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

Which tells me " " is an array of constant chars not a string.

This works:

```
636 $ cat foo.C
#include <string>
using std::string;
int main(void){
    string s = "hi";
    s += string(" ") + string("there!");
    return 0;
}
```